# Retrieving values from a PostgreSQL TEXT column with PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

We have an app based on JSF and JBoss that stores textual data into a regular PostgreSQL database.  When we are using our system via the JSF application, everything works perfectly, (i.e. we are able to retrieve, save and do everything else through the system).

We also have a PHP website, however, that retrieves information from the same database. The problem is that when it asks for information from any column of type TEXT, the database only outputs a series of numbers (it is using the value as if were a BLOB or CLOB, I think).  Because when I look directly into the database, I see the same number.

How should I go about solving this?

Comment: You say you look directly on the DB and "see the number", and PHP "retrieves a number"... so what's the problem? You have a number, you get a number... but aren't happy?

Comment: That is the problem when I look through my system (jsf) I see text, the text I wrote on my textfiedl, when I look on to the database I seea number like this "19674" instead of my text.  It is kind of acting like a CLOB, like it just gives me the address of the clob to retrieve.

Comment: When you say "look onto the database", what tool are you using? A visual data browser? An SQL query run through `psql` or `pgAdmin III` or `phpPgAdmin` or similar? Does the column show as type `text` if you look at the table structure in such tools, or is JSF interpreting TEXT and storing in some other way?

Comment: And what is the text you stored? Have you tried with a short string stored in the text column?

Comment: @IMPSoP, I am using pgadmin, I figured that in my system with jsf, the model had a lob notation, that makes it act like a CLOB, I took the lob notation and now it works.  I was more of a thing from hibernate that php and postgres I guess.

Comment: @JuanDiego Yeah, that makes sense. For future reference, Postgres will automatically store values in a `text` column in- or out-of-page as is required by the width of a particular row, so there's no need to include special handling for extra-long strings as there is in some DBMSes. A `VarChar(limit)` is just treated as a `text` column with a length constraint.

Comment: Meanwhile, if your problem is now solved, you're encouraged to add an answer explaining how you solved it and "accept" that answer so that others with a similar problem can find it.

Comment: @IMSoP, it was more like a work around I am still looking for a solution, I should be able to retrieve CLOB with php, I think. I am looking at fbsql por php.

Comment: @JuanDiego But why do you need a CLOB? Like I say, for 99% of use cases Postgres shouldn't need specific CLOB columns, as TEXT will store out-of-row automatically and transparently. If your framework is emulating CLOB using some other column type, then working around it there is more sensible than extending that erroneous logic to a PHP application.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would only need to emulate something like  a CLOB if you are storing so much text that a streaming API made sense.  I have yet to see a case for this in PostgreSQL, but if you did, you could use LOB's and just unescape in your app (they are basically BLOB's).

To pull a value from the db, it is generally well documented in PHP's documentation, but if you are using the pg_ functions, keep in mind that they do not loop over the result set for you (you need to do that yourself).  The modules in PEAR etc. may wrap that for you so make sure to consult your framework's documentation.